# Scale invariant curvature (plane curve)

Tags: reference-request, curves, curvature

Is there a form of curvature for a plane curve which is invariant under uniform scaling?

Ideally, I am looking for a way to characterize the effective 'local eccentricity' of a plane curve so that [geometrically] similar curves have identical curvature at  corresponding points - i.e. every circle has the same curvature regardless of radius, every parabola, every hyperbola with the same eccentricity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is probably the eccentricity of the *osculating conic*.

Note that a circle is defined by three points; this is why the osculating circle involves derivatives up to the second order.

Similarly, a general conic requires five points, and the osculating conic will take fourth derivatives.

Comment: I can see how that makes sense. Any idea how to go about determining the osculating conic given a parameterization of the plane curve by $\textbf{c}(t)$?

Comment: osculating from the Latin for "kissing".  Not to be confused with "oscillating".