# Formula for the osculating conic of a plane curve

Tags: calculus, curves, curvature, plane-curves

A follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127498/scale-invariant-curvature-plane-curve) question. Presumably similar curves have similar osculating conics, which in turn have identical eccentricities. Thus, the 'local eccentricity' of a plane curve at a point is the eccentricity of the osculating conic at that point.

While I have been able to find many, *many* methods for finding osculating circles, I cannot seem to find any for osculating conics. Is there a particular formula for finding the osculating conic given the parameterization of a plane curve?

Answer (score 4):

The generic equation of a conic can be written as: 
$$
ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0.
$$

Suppose your curve is given as $(x(t),y(t))$ and you want to find its osculating conic at $t=t_0$. If you define 
$$
F(t)=ax(t)^2+bx(t)y(t)+cy(t)^2+dx(t)+ey(t)+f
$$
then the following conditions must hold:
$$
F(t_0)=0,\quad F'(t_0)=0,\quad F''(t_0)=0,\quad F'''(t_0)=0,\quad F''''(t_0)=0.
$$
Solve the above system of equations to find coefficients $a,\dots ,f$.

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks:

a) I calculated some time ago exactly what you ask for and found e.g. a condition
that the osculating conic at a given point is an ellipse (resp. parabola, hyperbola), this is the case if $y'' y^{(4)} > \frac{5}{3}y'''^2$ (resp. =, <).
Thus one can classify points on a plane curve, e.g. all points on $y=e^x$ are hyperbolic (which is not obvious to the 'naked eye'). The aforementioned criterion is an affine differential invariant. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28044/osculating-conics-and-cubics-and-beyond

b) In the meantime Wolfram Alpha has implemented a function OsculatingConic: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OsculatingConic/

Answer (score 0):

Conic can osculate a curve at least up to $4$-th order of contact (multiplicity of $5$).

- $y$ as an explicit function in $x$ at $(0,0)$

\begin{align}
 0 &=
  9(y'')^4X^2+6(y'')^2 y''' X(Y-y' X) \\
 & \quad +[3y'' y^{(4)}-4(y''')^2](Y-y'X)^2-18(y'')^3 (Y-y'X)
\end{align}

- With parametrization

$$
0=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
  (X-x)^2 & 0 & x'^2 & 3x'x'' & 3x''^2+4x'x''' \\
  2(X-x)(Y-y) & 0 & 2x'y' & 3x'y''+3x''y' & 6x''y''+4x'y'''+4x'''y' \\
  (Y-y)^2 & 0 & y'^2 & 3y'y'' & 3y''^2+4y'y''' \\
  2(X-x) & x' & x'' & x''' & x'''' \\
  2(Y-y) & y' & y'' & y''' & y''''
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Please also refer to an article [*here*](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.35.1.43) and a book [*here*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-45450-3).